# Temp Table behavior with stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2008

I create a local temp table in a stored procedure that then calls another stored procedure that ALTERs the temp table by adding columns to it. `SELECT *` behaves as expected/desired in both the calling and the called stored procedure: the modified table columns are returned.

However, if I attempt to `SELECT [added column]`, I get an error 'invalid column'.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcA
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #BigTemp 
    (
        BigTempId INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
    );

    execute ProcB;

    SELECT * FROM #BigTemp;
END

CREATE PROCEDURE ProcB
AS
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE #BigTemp
    ADD ProductId int NULL;

    SELECT * FROM #BigTemp;
END
```

Execution of ProcA returns

```
BigTempId     ProductId
-----------------------
```

and

```
BigTempId     ProductId
-----------------------
```

Now, if I modify ProcB:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ProcB
AS
BEGIN
    ADD ProductId int NULL;
    SELECT ProductId FROM #BigTemp;
END
```

I'm rewarded with:

> Invalid column name 'ProductId'

Now, in my actual objects I'm creating the ALTER/ADD statement dynamically and executing it with `sp_executesql`, but the behavior is the same. It sure doesn't make any sense to me. Ideas?

Comment: Really I am wondering seeing this behavior

Comment: I think you've missed the 'ALTER TABLE #BigTemp'  line while altering 'ProcB'

Comment: Also, if I add 'SELECT ProductId FROM #BigTemp' in the calling sproc ProcA (removing it from ProcB), it runs just fine with no errors.

Comment: Rohit: yes I did when I transcribed the procedure to this post, but it's in the actual procedure. I saw this too late to edit it.

Comment: Issue is due to pre compilation .  add  WITH RECOMPILE  or exec with recomile

Answer (score 0):

I am still not getting why this behavior with Temp tables.

But below code do the trick to over come it.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE PROCA
    AS
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE #BIGTEMP 
        (
            BIGTEMPID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
        );
        EXECUTE PROCB;

         SELECT PRODUCTID  FROM #BIGTEMP B
    END

    ALTER PROCEDURE PROCB
    AS
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE #BIGTEMP
          ADD PRODUCTID INT NULL;

         SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM #BIGTEMP

         SELECT PRODUCTID FROM #TEMP

    END
```

Comment: I create the temp table as a 'dummy' in the outer sproc because I need it to be in that scope for subsequent processing. #TEMP in this example wouldn't be accessible where it's needed. What I think I can do is simply bust ProcB up into a couple of separate sprocs--do the alter and stop. ProcA can then call subsequent procedures to accomplish what my 'real' ProcB is currently trying to do.  Interestingly, I wrapped the ALTER TABLE statement in a transaction, and then nobody could see the added column, not even the calling procedure.

Comment: Did you got any explanation regarding this behaviour ??

Answer (score 0):

Issue is due to pre compilation . add WITH RECOMPILE or exec with recomile

Comment: Adding WITH RECOMPILE to both procedures on definition and/or to both procedures on execution didn't change anything at all--the same symptom occurs.